# Extract and display the single most frequently used Tag from a column value containing multiple Tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table I have created and I have also inserted the values:

```
CREATE TABLE Tag (
    Tag_Name NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<wedding-crashers>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><star-wars>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<comedy><the-pink-panther>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<plot-explanation><analysis><ending><tree-of-life>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<plot-explanation><the-departed>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<star-wars><darth-vader><casting>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><shutter-island>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<tree-of-life>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><tree-of-life>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<inception><existenz>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<effects><melancholia>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<hollywood><iranian>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<plot-explanation><pontypool>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<the-matrix><sequels><plot-explanation>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<editing><cut><metropolis>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<remake><akira>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<plot-explanation><ending><blue-valentine>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<star-wars><plot-explanation>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<plot-explanation><saving-private-ryan>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<film-industry>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><pulp-fiction>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><back-to-the-future><time-travel>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<analysis><quentin-tarantino><film-techniques><kill-bill>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<alfred-hitchcock><psychological-thriller><vertigo>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<production><bridesmaids>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<star-wars>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<book-adaptation><harry-potter>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<film-techniques><animation>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<remake><fantomas>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<muppets>')
INSERT INTO Tag (Tag_Name)
VALUES('<muppets>')
```

Now the question below is:

**Which single tag is most frequently used?**

In order to achieve this result, this is what I have tried:

```
SELECT Tag_Name AS 'Single most frequent Tag'
    , MAX([Tag Count]) AS 'Maximum Tag Count'
FROM (
    SELECT Tag_Name,COUNT(Tag_Name) AS 'Tag Count'
    FROM Tag
    GROUP BY Tag_Name
) A
GROUP BY Tag_Name
ORDER BY [Maximum Tag Count] DESC
```

And this is the result I have got which is shown below:

[image]

The problem with this result is that it is showing **muppets** is the most frequently used tag.
That is because the query recognized **muppets** as the only column value that has single tag in it.

If you see from the screenshot, probably **plot-explanation** OR **star-wars** is the most frequently used tag but they are not by themselves, and that is what my query is not able to recognize and isolate them.

What I am trying to achieve is to extract the most frequently used tag like **plot-explanation** OR **star wars** and Display the result with a single row something like which is shown below:

```
Single most common Tag  Maximum Tag Count
<plot-explanation>      26
```

I tried to achieve this result with my query but my query is not able to extract or isolate a tag like **plot-explanation** OR **star wars**.
Rather it only recognizes **muppets** that is because **muppets** is by itself and it is being repeated by itself in 2 different rows.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: what is the version of SQL Server that you are using?

Comment: Why isn't your data normalized?

Answer (score 3):

You should *normalize* your data and represent one tag per record.  Use this table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tag (
    ID int Tag_Group NOT NULL,
    Tag_Name NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

Here is the first part of your insert script, updated so that there is only one tag per record:

```sql
INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag_Name)
VALUES (1, '<wedding-crashers>');
INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag_Name)
VALUES (2, '<analysis>');
INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag_Name)
VALUES (2, '<star-wars>');
INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag_Name)
VALUES (3, '<comedy>');
INSERT INTO Tag (ID, Tag_Name)
VALUES (3, '<the-pink-panther>');
```

Now to find the tag(s) which have the most usage, you only need a simple aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Tag_Name
FROM Tag
GROUP BY Tag_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: @Dai Yes, we can make `Tag_Name` nullable if you wish.  As for your second comment, the whole point of this question is that a tag can appear multiple times.  If we make the tag name the PK, then each tag can appear a maximum of one time, which conflicts with the OP's problem statement.